# Particular View or Label of Segmented Control for Index

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uisegmentedcontrol

I want to reach particular view or label of segmented control. In my case, when user press the button, second part of segmented control should be blinked, not all of segmented control.

Also my blink func is here:

```
extension UIView{
func blink() {
    self.alpha = 0.2
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 0.0, options: [.curveLinear, .autoreverse], animations: {self.alpha = 1.0}, completion: nil)

}
```

}

Comment: try with once  `insertSegment` property of [uisegmentcontrol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol?changes=_3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can get the different segments of a segmented control as `UIView`s. I suspect that might involve using some private APIs.

Workarounds:

assuming your background color is white, you can add a white rectangular `UIView` on top of the segment that you want to flash. Adjust its size so that it covers second segment fully and animate that view's alpha: from 0 to 0.8, then to 0 again.

Alternatively, you can find a library that allows you to get the separate segments yourself. Or write your own `UIControl` subclass that exposes the segments.

Comment: I think your first solution is the most applicable. I’ll try. Thanks Sweeper!

Comment: @Oliver If you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!